# Initialise (and manage) basic auth database on AWS using htdbm

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-basic-authentication

I wish to protect a binary download on an AWS  using basic authentication. In the short term and as proof of concept I can use a password file. However, the number of users is likely to grow large enough to make a file-based solution a performance issue.

I have been trying to use htdbm to create and manage the user/password list like this:

```
sudo htdbm -c -T SDBM /var/www/.fileaccess.db
```

which returns:

```
Error opening database SDBM
This function has not been implemented on this platform
```

(I have tried using all of (SDBM|GDBM|DB|default)). Using dbmmanage is deprecated.

I don't understand exactly what function is not implemented on this platform, and I would be grateful for any assistance in how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space expected after `-T`.

```
$ sudo htdbm -c -TSDBM /path/to/file username
```

Remember not to put the database file in a place where it can be downloaded.

Comment: Is the correct answer, many thanks. The very few examples I could find had it wrong.